# What is the best way to use a discrete variable with a lot of classes in linear regression?

Tags: regression

I have a data set with a few discrete variables having a lot of classes(>100,000). This is too large to encode using a one-hot method. What is the best way to deal with such variables? Should I be using some other model?

I have yes/no responses to a set of questions and am trying to predict features based on these. But each user answers only a very small random subset of questions, so in order to make a prediction I need to determine the probability of answering yes/no for the rest of the questions.

Comment: Several questions:  Please tell us N and the measurement level of your dependent variable(s)... Are your variables with >100,000 classes Xs or Ys?...For how many variables, or for how many levels of a given variable, are you trying to impute values?...Why do you need to impute values in order to make predictions?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would like to try regularisation that works on the levels of the categorical variable, for example a type of group LASSO approach. See e.g. Gertheiss, J. and Tutz, G. (2010): Sparse Modeling of Categorial Explanatory Variables, The Annals of Applied Statistics, 4, 2150-2180 http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1421
This will automatically cluster the categories in a LASSO path and conduct variable selection.

Additionally, please take care not to use linear regression in the case of binary responses or their probabilities, it is suboptimal (rather use a glm for binary data or proportions).

Another possibility would be to use recursive partitioning (classification trees), which will greedily search for a stepwise function through the whole space spanned by the categories of the predictors and select one at each step. If interpretation of the tree structure is of interest, use an unbiased algorithm such as GUIDE or ctree, if prediction is more important CART or C4.5 will do.

Comment: I will try the approach in the paper and see how it works. I don't think decision trees will work given the classes are not ordinal and one hot encoding is not feasible, I could try using them once I  reduce the dimentionality.

Comment: The paper uses an approach that requires a function of all variables(produced with one hot encoding) to be minimized so it can't be used for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try reducing the number of classes. More classes for relatively less number of observations creates big problems for linear regression. For example, if your variables have classes 1 to 5, introduce one variable for classes 1-3 and some other for 4-5. This thing of course depends upon the number of your classes, number of variables and most crucially upon number of observations.

As for other models, it depends. Dummy variables work fine in normal least squares method. Or you can also use a logistic model. Just make sure that number of observations is considerably more than number of variables and number of classes.

If you want to use data as it it, partial least squares may be useful-it is designed to be used when number of observations are comparable with number of variables. But for a huge number of classes, I don't know whether it will work or not.

Comment: I added some more information. I can't think of a reasonable way of  grouping the data. Grouping questions subjectively is not helpful since it does not help determine likely response. I can't cluster people by similar responses because the data is too sparse. I haven't used PLS - but will I not have the same problem with the input variables?

Comment: I am not saying that you group questions subjectively. Just that the sparsity problem can be tackled to some degree with the method I suggested. The problem of users answering only small subset of questions remains, though. I shall try to see how that can be done and reply back.

Comment: Well, you can always select the requisite subset of questions by using dependancy analysis, feature selection methods, etc. Once you have reduced number of variables, use more representative classes and you are done.